# Two onclicks at the same time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, onclick, whmcs

I have been working on a project and came across a problem.

This is the html portion :

```
<a href="#" onclick="doDeleteLine('86');return false" data-hiddenid="90" id="delbtn0"></a>
```

The onclick is by default in the code and working fine. I have written another onclick as follows :

```
$("#delbtn'.$k.'").on("click", function(e){
    var check_id = $("#delbtn'.$k.'").data("hiddenid");
    var baseurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/";
    $.post("quotes.php?action=manage&id='.$_GET['id'].'", { hiddenid: check_id }, function(data){
    location.reload();
    });
});
```

While running the code (literally a delete button which deletes a row of data), the both onclicks are being called and executed.

But sometimes, I have to refresh once the page has been loaded in order to see the changes from second on click feature.

Is there a way i could solve this? or control which onclick to be executed first ?

Note : Everything is working as it should except this need to refresh inorder to see the change.

Comment: This is because you are passing `doDeleteLine()` and click event both

Comment: Voting to close as a typographical error.

Comment: Why do you need 2 event handlers?

Comment: You should consider using classes instead of appended IDs for this type of operation.  When you use classes, you may trigger a click event when any '#delbtn' is clicked and then you may access that input/div's properties with jquery's '$(this)' definition.  And on another note, why not just put all actions associated with the click event inside of the jquery click function?  You are using both inline function calls and jquery events to do the same thing.  I advise doing it all with jquery.

Comment: Thank you everyone for commenting regarding my issue but please note these things :

Comment: The doDeleteLine() function is there by default and i don't have access to that function. And sure @Luke will try as u suggested with classes . To make this understandable please know this : the jquery i wrote deletes rows from a custom table where as doDeleteLine() deletes from default table, its displayed as one in the page thats all.

Comment: How is this related to WHMCS? why tagged WHMCS?

Comment: Because this is being done in WHMCS quotes section. @wesamly